# How do i get all directory and files in my github repository by using github api?

Tags: git, github

As the title said. i want get all files and directory from github api.

I found this https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents.

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

this api said `Gets the contents of a file or directory in a repository. Specify the file path or directory in :path. If you omit :path, you will receive the contents of all files in the repository.`

I call this api without `:path` it just return file or directory in `root` path.

response data have `git_url` field. it have `/repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:sha` api url.
this api return file and directory of that have.

#### My question

1. Is there a way to get all file and directory information in my repository by calling GitHub api only once?
2. If `1.` is impossible, do I have to recursively call the api (aforementioned `git_url` field) to get all the files and directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation to which you have provided a link, it says:

> To get a repository's contents recursively, you can recursively [get the tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/).

If you read that documentation, there is a a "[Get a tree recursively](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively)" heading which has exactly what you want:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:tree_sha?recursive=1
```

Comment: This doesn't explain where do I get "tree sha" and how do I use this endpoint if I need to get files from some folder in the repo recursively.

Comment: As with `git` itself you get a tree SHA from a commit (and you get a commit using the [commit api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#get-a-commit)). Then use the API referenced in this answer, which returns a list of files and sub-trees, and walk down it recursively to find the content in which you're interested.

Comment: You can also pass a branch name in the place of tree sha

Answer (score 1):

You can get all files and folders by calling the tree API recursively for a branch:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/git/trees/{BRANCH}?recursive=1
```